# Vertauschen von Haupt- und Nebensatz, wenn Nebensatz ein Lokalsatz ist

Tags: grammar, phrase

Ich habe die folgenden Sätze:

> Bleib, wo du bist!
>
> Er ging zurück, woher er kam.
>
> Geh, wohin das Herz dich trägt!

Meine Frage ist, ob ich Haupt-und Nebensatz in diesen Sätzen vertauschen und folgenderweise schreiben kann:

> Wo du bist, bleib!
>
> Woher er kam, ging er zurück.
>
> Wohin das Herz dich trägt, geh!

Ich denke schon und frage mich, wieso nicht? Allerdings habe ich versucht zu googeln, aber ich kann keine Bespiele für meine Frage finden.

Comment: Theoretisch und grammatikalisch würde das wohl gehen, es klingt aber unidiomatisch. Nur Dichter würden, um des Reimes oder Versmaßes willen, das vielleicht tun.

Comment: Ich frage mich gerade, ob man hier von Haupt-/Nebensatz sprechen kann? Kennt jemand die genaue Bezeichnung für das Konstrukt.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Laut canoo.net handelt es sich m.E. bei allen drei Beispielen

- **formal** um zusammengesetzte Sätze aus einem Hauptsatz und einem durch ein [Frageadverb](http://canoonet.eu/services/OnlineGrammar/Wort/Adverb/Klasse/Frage.html) eingeleiteten [Pronominalsatz](http://canoonet.eu/services/OnlineGrammar/Satz/Komplex/Form/eingeleitet.html#Anchor-3800) (Nebensatz)

und

- **funktional** um [Lokalsätze](http://canoonet.eu/services/OnlineGrammar/Satz/Komplex/Funktion/Adverbial/Lokal.html) (als Unterfall von Adverbialsätzen und nur auf den Nebensatz bezogen).

Zwar können Adverbialsätze grundsätzlich auch vor dem Hauptsatz stehen:

> **Weil es regnet**, spielen sie im Haus.

Das geht aber m.E. bei Lokalsätzen nicht, da sie enger mit einer Komponente des Hauptsatzes zusammenhängen und diese näher bestimmen. Solange diese Komponente des Hauptsatzes nicht bekannt ist, hängen sie "in der Luft". Sie sind daher für mich eng mit den "[weiterführenden Nebensätzen](http://canoonet.eu/services/OnlineGrammar/Satz/Komplex/Funktion/Weiterfuehrend.html)" verwandt, die **nach** dem Hauptsatz stehen müssen (erst mit dem Hauptsatz existiert etwas, was weitergeführt werden kann).

EDIT:

Wenn man das [Feldermodell](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feldermodell_des_deutschen_Satzes) zugrunde legen möchte, könnte der Lokalsatz im Vorfeld stehen, wenn er entweder (im Sinne eines [Topik](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topik_(Linguistik))) das Satzthema vorgibt, oder wenn sein Inhalt kontrastierend hervorgehoben werden soll. Für die erste Funktion hat die Wikipedia ein [gutes Beispiel](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adverbialsatz#Lokalsatz_.28.C3.B6rtliche_Angabe.29):

> Wo sich Fuchs und Hase gute Nacht sagen, lebt er.

Aus stilistischen Gründen kann man also in bestimmten Fällen die Abfolge der Teilsätze vertauschen; es bedarf m.E. aber eines "rechtfertigenden Grundes".

Answer (score 4):

Wenn diese Umkehrung überhaupt benutzt wird, dann meistens mit einem zusätzlichen Demonstrativpronomen:

> Wo du bist, da bleibe!

Anderenfalls wäre sie ziemlich schwer zu verstehen.

Comment: Laut Duden [ist _da_ ein Adverb](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/da_Adverb_dort_hier), genau wie _dahin_, das in den beiden anderen Sätzen die naheliegendste Ergänzung wäre. Ich verstehe die originalen Sätze übrigens so, dass in ihnen diese Adverben weggelassen wurden, aber (bei gleichbleibender Bedeutung) drinstehen könnten.